# What are the performance drawbacks of using global symbols in a getter and setter methods?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

The JavaScript code below has a getter and setter for `name` using global symbols, and `age_` using a dangling underscore.

**JavaScript Code**

```js
function Human(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age_ = age;
}

Human.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.name}! You are ${this.age} years old.`);
};

Human.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield* Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
  yield* Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this);
};

Object.defineProperties(
  Human.prototype,
  {
    name: {
      get() {
        return this[Symbol.for('name')];
      },
      set(value) {
        this[Symbol.for('name')] = value;
      },
    },
    age: {
      get() {
        return this.age_;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.age_ = value;
      },
    },
  },
);

let mary = new Human('Mary Smith', 18);
mary.greet();
console.dir(mary);

let john = new Human('John Doe', 25);
john.greet();
console.dir(john);
```

**Console Output**
[image: Console output of the JavaScript code]

I want to know is there any performance drawbacks to using global symbols for a getter and setter methods because I find it much cleaner code.

Comment: Performance drawbacks. Probably no. Readability drawbacks: yes. Can't you just use a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

Comment: I want to learn both prototype and class based OOP since I don't think prototypes are avoidable in JavaScript.

Worst case about dangling underscore is `mary.age_` don't call the getter for age and it also changes the value for `mary.age`. So you have to carry that baggage of remembering not to change `mary.age_`.